# How to assert multiple values in JSONPath Match Configuration in SOAPUI - REST

Tags: api, automation, soapui, rest

I have a REST API response like this.

{
"success": true,
"response":    [
{
"id": 123,
"documentType": "Test",
"documentTypeId": 0,
"title": "title",
"description": "",

is there a way that I can assert multiple values at once.
i.e. I want to verify id returns 123 and documentType returns Test, in the same Assertions.

I tried using JSONPath Match Config in different ways, but couldn't figure out a way

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A0AaV.png)

Comment: Hi, if you want some sort of conditional assertion where.... if val1 equals A, then val2 must equal something else... then use a script assertion.

Comment: Hi Thanks a lot. I sorted my issue! :)

Comment: You could buy a license to get access to https://support.smartbear.com/readyapi/docs/testing/assertions/reference/property/message.html Or roll your own using a Groovy Script assertion.